# Extracting values from XML files for analysis in R through different ways

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to extract values from XML files for analysis in R through different ways. The url of xml file is:
http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputbyFuelHourly/PUB_GenOutputbyFuelHourly_2015.xml.

```r
library(XML)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)  

data<-"http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputbyFuelHourly/PUB_GenOutputbyFuelHourly_2015.xml"
xmlfile=xmlParse(data)
class(xmlfile) #"XMLInternalDocument" "XMLAbstractDocument"

xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlfile) #gives content of root
class(xmltop)#"XMLInternalElementNode" "XMLInternalNode" "XMLAbstractNode"
xmlName(xmltop) #give name of node, PubmedArticleSet
xmlSize(xmltop) #how many children in node, 19
xmlName(xmltop[[1]]) #name of root's children

class(data)
str(data)
topxml <- xmlRoot(data)
topxml <- xmlSApply(topxml,
                   function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
xml_df <- data.frame(t(topxml),
                     row.names=NULL)
```

Earlier I have always used csv file. xml data is first time and 'am trying since yesterday.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to extract?

Comment: A data frame for further analysis of data.

Comment: Like the one below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to get this into a data.frame. I looked at the xml structure of the document you provided and from what I could gather, you have data that you want to look at with columns of:  `c("date", "hour", "fuel_type", "quality", "fuel_output")`. Using xpath is the way to go, which a good start is [here](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xpath-tutorial)

If that's the case, here's the code I used to accomplish this, note that it is extremely slow...and for some reason node 84 throws an error.. but this should get you started:

```
# Read in the raw document
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
raw <- read_html('http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputbyFuelHourly/PUB_GenOutputbyFuelHourly_2015.xml')

# Use xpath to get all nodes for <DailyData>, which is actually lowercase in the doc
daily_nodes <- xml_find_all(raw, ".//dailydata")

# loop through and extract the information from the childnoded
# 
o <- lapply(daily_nodes,function(i){
    day <- xml_find_all(i, ".//day") %>% xml_text()
    hourly <- xml_find_all(i, ".//hourlydata")
    tryCatch({
        jsonlite::rbind_pages(lapply(hourly, function(j){
        n_hour <- xml_find_all(hourly, ".//hour") %>% xml_text() %>% as.numeric()
        fuel_type <- xml_find_all(j, ".//fueltotal/fuel") %>% xml_text()
        fuel_qual <- xml_find_all(j, ".//descendant::outputquality") %>% xml_text() %>% as.numeric()
        fuel_output <- xml_find_all(j, ".//descendant::output") %>% xml_text() %>% as.numeric()
        data.frame(hour = n_hour, type = fuel_type, qual = fuel_qual, output = fuel_output)
    })) %>% mutate(date = day) %>% select(date, 1:4)
    }, error = function(e){
        NA
    })
})
# This will be the data.frame with all info
odf <- jsonlite::rbind_pages(o[mapply(is.data.frame,o)])
# Number of rows
> nrow(odf)
[1] 209664
# Showing number of hourly records for just one date...
> filter(odf, date == "2015-01-01") %>% count(hour)
# A tibble: 24 x 2
    hour     n
   <dbl> <int>
 1     1    24
 2     2    24
 3     3    24
 4     4    24
 5     5    24
 6     6    24
 7     7    24
 8     8    24
 9     9    24
10    10    24
# … with 14 more rows

# Showing how many records per date exist
> count(odf, date)
# A tibble: 364 x 2
   date           n
   <chr>      <int>
 1 2015-01-01   576
 2 2015-01-02   576
 3 2015-01-03   576
 4 2015-01-04   576
 5 2015-01-05   576
 6 2015-01-06   576
 7 2015-01-07   576
 8 2015-01-08   576
 9 2015-01-09   576
10 2015-01-10   576
# … with 354 more rows
```

Run your analysis on `odf`

Comment: Thanks ..worked . I had to include library(jasonlite) ,as  it was giving "_Error in rbind_pages(o[mapply(is.data.frame, o)]) : 
  could not find function "rbind_pages_"

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Glad it worked. Mind accepting the answer if so?

Comment: Sorry to bother you . Were do I need to change in the _code_  to get other Date data ? _Thanks_

Comment: Can you be more specific re:dateData? Do you mean the node that fails(84)?

Comment: Displayed report gives fuel output of first hour of Jan 1st only . Where in the _code_ I need to change to go for second hour and further for other dates ? _Thanks_

Comment: @krofox when you run the code.... are you including the `%>% head()` in the end? If so.. get rid of it...